# C - trying to read a single char from stdin (and failing) w/ scanf / getchar

Tags: c, scanf

as a part of a homework assignment, I'm trying to read a single char from stdin, and act according to it:

```
char choice;

while (1) {
    printf("please enter [y]es, [n]o or [m]aybe: ");
    scanf("%c", choice);
    fflush(stdin);
    // validate input
    if (choice == 'y' || choice == 'n' || choice == 'm') {
        break;
    } else {
      printf("Please enter only \'y\', \'n\' or \'m\'!\n");
    }
}
// do something with the input
if (choice == 'y') {
    printf("you selected yes!\n");
}
```

for some reason, scanf captures both the char and the line-feed after, thus it proceeds to do something with the input and then also prints the "Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!" line. If I enter several characters on the stdin, it will print that line for all of them, while also performing correctly for the first char. So, for example:

```
$ ./run
please enter [y]es, [n]o or [m]aybe: y<return>
you selected yes!
Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!
$ ./run
please enter [y]es, [n]o or [m]aybe: yes<return>
you selected yes!
Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!
Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!
Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!
$
```

Same thing happens if I use getchar. What am I missing? thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a space between `scanf("` and the `%c` for it to work correctly:

```
scanf(" %c", &choice);
```

And you also need to use &choice, not choice!

EDIT: While you're at it, you might want to look into `do while()` for that loop (unless the professor specifically said to use a `break`) - `do while` works great when validating user input!

Comment: Until you get unexpected input; try entering "y x z" for example.

Comment: LOL what a legend!

Answer (score 6):

`fflush()` is not defined by ISO C for input streams.  It is defined in Microsoft's C runtime library, but is not portable.

While the "space before %c" solution may work when the user enters the expected data, it will fail in many ways; try entering "y n y n" for example.  Console input is line oriented; your best bet is to ensure that you discard the entire line thus:

```
scanf( "%c", &choice ) ;
while( choice != '\n' && getchar() != '\n' ) /* do nothing*/ ;
```

Answer (score 4):

Better still, use fgetc(). scanf() should always be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will keep it brief.Because of insufficient points to submit a comment 
If we can see that number of o/p is (one + the no of charcter)
This is beacuse when we hit enter after entering the characters '\n' which is non-printable character also gets added after your string.

```
$ ./run
please enter [y]es, [n]o or [m]aybe: y<return>
you selected yes!
Please enter only 'y', 'n' or 'm'!  -----------> it is due to reading of the '\n' by scanf
```

> EDITED
>   Due to insufficient points I could post this as a comment.This is a workaround of the above answers

Comment: that is a workaround for the problem, isn't it? So it is a comment to the question (not an answer).

Comment: Dont hav sufficient points I wanted to but didn't know that I will be donwnvoted for this.