# scanf won't ask for input the second time

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void)
{

     int order, nextp, N=3;
     char cont;
     nextp = 0;
     printf("\nShould we continue (y or n): ");
     scanf("%c", &cont);
     if (cont != 'y') return;
     for(; nextp < N; nextp++)
     {
        printf("Enter order number: ");
        scanf("%d", &order);
        printf("you have entered %d\n", order);
        printf("okay now continue with cont\n");


        printf("enter cont y or n: ");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
        if (cont != 'y')
        {
            printf("\nnot equal to y\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("after intepreting t[0]");
      }

   return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this

```
Should we continue (y or n): y
Enter order number: 45
you have entered 45
okay now continue with cont
enter cont y or n: 
not equal to y
```

The second input was skipped. Why?

Comment: This has been discussed a zillion times on SO. Try doing a little research on existing questions

Answer (score 11):

because of newline character already in stdin , this is happening.
use

```
scanf(" %c", &cont);
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", &cont);
```

note one space before %c.

Answer (score 4):

After `scanf("%d", &order);` consumes the number (45 in this case), there is still a newline left after that. You can use `scanf("%d\n", &order)` to make it consume the return.

Another answer to this can be found here:

[scanf() leaves the new line char in buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer)

Answer (score 3):

This is why `scanf` is not typically preferred for character input.  There's a left over carriage return after the previous input.

For example, if you were to add a `getchar()` after the order input, your problem would be solved, but that's not clean code. You can also see this explicitly by subsituting `cont != 'y'` to `cont != '\n'`.

Instead, use `getchar()` for all your input and check for \n

Comment: Okay I will try that in a bit. But I tried `fgets(..)` and it suffers too and it was supposed to be safer.

Comment: Again, fgets includes the newline at the end. Simply replace the newline with a null before inputting the value

Answer (score 1):

For most conversions scanf will skip whitespace, but for char format ("%c") you must skip white space by using an explicit space in the format (" %c") as explained here:

[C - trying to read a single char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959255/c-trying-to-read-a-single-char-from-stdin-and-failing-w-scanf-getchar)

This is also explained in the [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) documentation, but it's confusing and may be better to use something else as others have mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fflush()

```
printf("enter cont y or n: ");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c", &cont);
```