# new to c, whats wrong with my code

Tags: c, scanf

Please help me with this obviously silly mistake

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctime>

int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int No_of_Q = 0;            //number of questions 
    int m1, m2, ans;            //two operands and answer
    int ra = 0;                 //number of right answers
    int wa = 0;                 //number of wrong answers
    char c = 'y';               //whether to continue

    printf("Let's play multiply!\n");
    do 
    {
        printf("How many questions would you like to attempt? ");
        scanf_s("%d", &No_of_Q);
        printf("\n");

        for(int i=1; i<=No_of_Q; i++)
        {
            m1=(rand()%10 + 1);
            m2=(rand()%10 + 1);

            printf("\nWhat is %d x %d = ", m1, m2);
            scanf_s("%d",&ans);

            if(ans== m1*m2)
            {
               printf("Your answer is correct!\n");
               ra++ ;
            }
            else{
            printf("Wrong, the correct answer is %d.\n", m1*m2);
            wa++ ;
            } 
        }
        printf("\n\nOut of %d answers, %d were correct and %d wrong.\n",No_of_Q, ra, wa);
        if(wa==0)
            printf("Congratulations!\n");
        else
            printf("Better luck next time!\n");
        printf("Continue game? ");
        scanf_s("%c", &c );      /*-------CANNOT GET THIS TO PERFORM--------------*/
        //printf("%c",c);
    }
      while(c=='y');

      return 0;
}
```

I am using vs 2012 express edition.
I cannot get my program to scan answer to continue at the end of the program.
The while statement at the end doesn't compute.
Please help.

Comment: First of all your question is not clear.You need to post the error .This is the reason no one trying to give you the solution.

Comment: See, for example, [`scanf()` won't ask for input the second time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372923/scanf-wont-ask-for-input-the-second-time) as one of many similar questions.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx `scanf_s` need for `%s`, `%c` Eg `scanf_s("%c", &c, 1);`

Comment: The title is very unclear, try to modify it to reflect the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your line `scanf_s("%d", &ans);` reads up to but not including the newline after the number.  The `scanf_s("%c", &c);` then reads the newline, which is not `'y'`, so the loop fails.

This is why you will find many people (myself included) recommended reading the response with `fgets()` and then converting the input with `sscanf_s()`.

You should also check that `scanf_s()` returns the correct value (1 for the two calls mentioned) — or that `fgets()` and `sscanf_s()` return the correct values (`fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0` and `sscanf_s(...) == 1)`).

You should also note that `#include <ctime>` is C++ header; the C header is `#include <time.h>`.  I don't see any use of `#include <conio.h>`, so you could omit that.

---

Additionally, you are mis-calling [`scanf_s()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) when using the `%c` conversion. As [BluePixy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171563/new-to-c-whats-wrong-with-my-code#comment26622616_18171563), you should be passing a length of 1 after the `&c`:

```
if (scanf("%c", &c, 1U) != 1)
    ...oops...
```

The C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:2011) Annex K covers the Bounds-checking Interfaces and says much the same.

Comment: So, what's the solution?

Comment: I already told you the solution I'd use: read a line of input using `fgets()` and then use `sscanf_s()` to convert the input.  And I'd error check the inputs before using the results.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf_s("%c", &c );` function two times instead of one. The frist one will get the `'\n'`
character and then it will be replaced by your input.

```
printf("Continue game? ");
scanf_s("%c", &c );      /*-------WILL GET '\n'--------------*/
scanf_s("%c", &c );      /*-------WILL ASK FOR INPUT--------------*/
```