# Allocating Memory for a single character within a struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the following code I am trying to create an array of struct pointers which will hold 2 structures. I think my problem has something to do with the allocation of memory of the character. The code itself is self-explanatory but I can't seem to fix the issue when scanning for the second char variable.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Structure
{
    char character ;
    char* string ;
    int integer ;
    float floatingPoint ;
    
} Structure ;
    
void *insertData(struct Structure *x)
{
    int i ;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter a character: ") ;
        scanf("%c", &x[i].character) ;
        
        printf("Enter an integer: ") ;
        scanf("%d", &x[i].integer) ;
        
        printf("Enter a string: ") ;
        scanf("%s", x[i].string) ;
        
        printf("Enter a floating point: ") ;
        scanf("%f", &x[i].floatingPoint) ;
    }
}

void printData(struct Structure *x)
{
    int i ;
    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n\t Pointer: \n") ;
        printf("Character: %c\n", x[i].character) ;
        printf("Integer: %d\n", x[i].integer) ;
        printf("String: %s\n", x[i].string) ;
        printf("Floating Point: %f\n", x[i].floatingPoint) ;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i ;
    struct Structure* pointers = (struct Structure*) malloc(2 * sizeof(struct Structure)) ;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        //allocating mem for string
        pointers[i].string = malloc(sizeof(char)) ;
    }
    
    insertData(pointers) ;
    printData(pointers) ;


    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter a character: A                                                            
Enter an integer: 69                                                            
Enter a string: Sheeesh                                                         
Enter a floating point: 6.9                                                     
Enter a character: Enter an integer: 111                                        
Enter a string: string                                                          
Enter a floating point: 1.1  

Character: A                                                                    
Integer: 69                                                                     
String: Sheeesh                                                                 
Floating Point: 6.900000 
                                                                                                                                             
Character:                                                                      
                                                                                
Integer: 111                                                                    
String: string                                                                  
Floating Point: 1.10000
```

Comment: What issue do you have? Btw. you use `typedef struct Structure`, so there is no need to write `struct Structure` all the time, just use `Structure`.

Comment: The output looks fine, but why are you trying to store "Sheeesh" in a string only large enough for one char (which should really be \0)?

Comment: I think the issue is scanf doesn't let you enter the second character. This may be a dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372923/scanf-wont-ask-for-input-the-second-time

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I removed the struct Structures (which was working but pointless) and it was fixed by changing "%c" to "  %c"! I thought it was a memory problem, but seems not.

Answer (score 2):

You allocate just a single byte (AKA `sizeof (char)`) for the string. That's not enough.