# Issue with scanf() in C

Tags: c, scanf

I am learning by myself how to code using the C languange. In order to study this latter a bit more in depth, I'm doing some basic exercises and, due to this, today I have faced a little issue using the `scanf()` instruction. Infact, the following code:

```
int main() {

  char inputOne;
  char inputTwo;

  printf("Insert a char: ");
  scanf("%c", &inputOne);
  // &inputOne is the pointer to inputOne.

  printf("Insert another char: ");
  scanf("%c", &inputTwo);

  if (inputOne == inputTwo) {
    printf("You have inserted the same char!\n");
    printf("Chars inserted: %c, %c\n", inputOne, inputTwo);
  } else {
    printf("You have inserted two different chars!\n");
    printf("Chars inserted: %c, %c\n", inputOne, inputTwo);
  }

}
```

when compiled does not return any error, but when I launch the application on the Terminal, I am not able to insert the second character.
Here is an example of what happens:

```
Macbook-Pro-di-Rodolfo:~ Rodolfo$ /Users/Rodolfo/Documents/GitHub/Fondamenti\ di\ C/esempio-if-else ; exit;
Insert a char: a
Insert a second char: You have inserted two different chars!
Chars inserted: a, 

logout

[Process completed]
```

Can anybody explain me why this happens?

Comment: One of the *hundreds* of duplicates of this question [can be found **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959255/c-trying-to-read-a-single-char-from-stdin-and-failing-w-scanf-getchar).

Comment: @user3121023 do the number of spaces before or after the conversion specification influence the final result? With other words, are `scanf(" %c", &inputTwo)` and `scanf("     %c", &inputTwo)` identical for the compiler?

Comment: @user3121023 I'm sorry, it is not properly visible in my first comment but I was meaning if `scanf()` behaves in the same way indipendently from the number of white spaces between the quotation mark and the conversion specification `%`. In other words, if `<space><space><space>%c` and `<space>%c` outputs the same stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes `line feed` as input to the second character. You can take the `inputTwo` again to prevent it:

```
int main() {

  char inputOne;
  char inputTwo;

  printf("Insert a char: ");
  scanf("%c", &inputOne);
  // &inputOne is the pointer to inputOne.

  printf("Insert another char: ");
  scanf("%c", &inputTwo);
  scanf("%c", &inputTwo);

  if (inputOne == inputTwo) {
    printf("You have inserted the same char!\n");
    printf("Chars inserted: %c, %c\n", inputOne, inputTwo);
  } else {
    printf("You have inserted two different chars!\n");
    printf("Chars inserted: %c, %c\n", inputOne, inputTwo);
  }

}
```